# Awaiting recommendation, but before any sort of peer review

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission, journal-workflow

I submitted a paper through ScholarOne Manuscripts 3 days ago. The first status that I am getting is "**ADM: Awaiting Recommendation**" , just after the initial status which was "ADM: Waiting for Admin Processing". I know the typical stages of a journal workflow. My Q is, has anyone had any experience with the particular status? Should I expect an outright desk rejection?
N.B. I am aware that **Awaiting Recommendation** is generally seen post peer review. But mine is not the case as listed above. That is what confused me.

Comment: To me it means that the paper is with the referees.

Comment: Can you share the site you submitted this on? I can get you a specific answer.